# FATAL EXCEPTION: main (https://github.com/luiscolqu/AppFunDrinks.git)

Tags: android-studio

Código:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        />
    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Error:

```
11-24 04:06:39.879 27999-27999/pe.edu.utp.fundrinks D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-24 04:06:39.879 27999-27999/pe.edu.utp.fundrinks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: pe.edu.utp.fundrinks, PID: 27999
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pe.edu.utp.fundrinks/pe.edu.utp.fundrinks.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                      at pe.edu.utp.fundrinks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
                                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:463)
                                                                      at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
                                                                      at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                      at pe.edu.utp.fundrinks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Deberías explicar lo que pasa, que error te da, cuando te da ese error, si has intentado algo...

Comment: Revisa [ask], debes agregar información en el cuerpo de la pregunta ser más especifico, aportar detalles. ¿cual es la pregunta?, considera agregar el código de la clase FAB